# DateTime.ParseExact to sortable format throws exception

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to ParseCurrent time to sortable dateFormat which is stated below. 
THis dateFormat is working in another part of application where I am getting time string right from the server, but when I need to use current time  it gives me an exception. Anybody any suggestion please?

```
string dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz";
updateBook.orderFrom = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString(), dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you converting `DateTime.Now` to a string just to parse it into a `DateTime` again?

Comment: I am not sure why you are converting a DateTime instance to a string and then immediately parsing it back again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
updateBook.orderFrom = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Aside from perhaps a few milliseconds difference, wouldn't this equal `updateBook.orderFrom = DateTime.Now;`?

Answer (score 1):

better you can try

```
var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffzzz")
```